# Create the same hash in PHP as OracleMembershipProvider

Tags: c#, php, .net, oracle, hash

I want to compare hash created with OracleMembershipProvider method:

```
CreateUser(username, password, e-mail)
```

with hash manually created in php. 
CreateUser method saves password hash and salt in db.
I must add that salt values are different for each password.

I dont know th pattern that OracleMembershipProvider is using for hash generating.
since my .NET application is 4.5 framework and hash algorithmtype is not specified I presume
sha-1 is used.

I just want to get pattern of hash generation so I can compare it and use the same db for PHP application log in.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finnally found an answer:

password generation with OracleMembershipProvider is the same as in SQLMembershipProvider.
so this question has the same answer as here:
[What is default hash algorithm that ASP.NET membership uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137368/what-is-default-hash-algorithm-that-asp-net-membership-uses)

this function works OK for me.

```
public string EncodePassword(string pass, string salt)
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass);
            //byte[] src = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(salt); Corrected 5/15/2013
            byte[] src = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);
            byte[] dst = new byte[src.Length + bytes.Length];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 0, dst, 0, src.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, dst, src.Length, bytes.Length);
            HashAlgorithm algorithm = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA1");
            byte[] inArray = algorithm.ComputeHash(dst);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(inArray);
        }
```

Edit:
All i had to do is to convert this code into PHP.
I found this conversion: [Trying to port C# function to PHP5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516440/trying-to-port-c-sharp-function-to-php5)